# How to rerender when Redux state is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I have 2 components.

The first component provides a read (useSelector) from the Redux state object and renders its contents
The second component ensures the insertion of new data into the same Redux state object

How to achieve that when a Redux state object changes with the help of the second component, the first component captures this change and renders the new content of the object again.

I tried to add in the component element:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...some actions
}, [reduxStateObject]);
```

But it gives me too many requests.

/// EDIT add real example

1. component

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ToDoList = () => {
  const { todos } = useSelector((state) => state.global);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Active</h1>
      {todos
        ?.filter((todo) => !todo.isCompleted)
        .sort((a, b) => (a.deadline < b.deadline ? 1 : -1))
        .map((todo, id) => {
          const date = new Date(todo.deadline).toLocaleString();

          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <p>{todo.text}</p>
              <p>{date}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToDoList;
```

2. component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getToDoItems } from "../redux/globalSlice";

import ToDoList from "../components/ToDoList";

const ToDoWall = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getToDoItems(1));
  }, [dispatch]);
  
    const submitForm = (e) => {
    dispatch(postToDoItem(e.data));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToDoList />
      <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default ToDoWall;
```

/// EDIT add Reducer

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  todos: null,
};

export const globalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "global",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setItems: (state, action) => {
      state.todos = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setItems } = globalSlice.actions;

export default globalSlice.reducer;

// Load todo items
export const getToDoItems = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://xxx.mockapi.io/api/list/${id}/todos`)
      .then((resp) => dispatch(setItems(resp.data)));
  };
};

// Post a list name
export const postNameList = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post("https://xxx.mockapi.io/api/list", {
      name: data,
    });
  };
};

// Post a todo item
export const postToDoItem = (id, data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(
      `https://xxx.mockapi.io/api/list/${id}/todos`,
      {
        listId: id,
        title: data.title,
        text: data.text,
        deadline: +new Date(data.deadline),
        isCompleted: false,
      }
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi, hope I can understand your question correctly.
So you have **2 Component**, you want to update **Component One** when **Component Two** modified the state?

Comment: you are changing the reduxStateObject over and over check where are you doing that ,

Comment: @WesleyLoh Hi, Exactly. You got it right.

Comment: You can refer to this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dmedan?file=src%2FApp.js). There are some code comment, you can read it. Hope its helped.

Comment: @WesleyLoh I tried it, but I still don't see the newly added todos until after the refresh. (I modified the original question and added real codes)

Comment: @TheDareback You can refer to  the previous stackblitz again, I modified it.
In your case, I don't think you need to use **useEffect**

Comment: @WesleyLoh I looked at your file and when I tried it on a new project, everything worked great. But in an current project, the problem is probably more in the slice file. I also added a slice to the original question. Would you please help me?

Comment: @TheDareback , Icic, form the new code you provide, it can saw that actually you are doing something related to **async**, the example I give is assuming you are not doing async work. To do thing with async. You need to use **createAsyncThunk** function. Pleasse refer to the official doc on how to do it. [Here is the link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#overview). Hope its helps

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you don't need to do anything. When you dispatch action to change state in redux store, it'll change, and all components that use that state will get it, you don't need to worry about updating anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the original question and added real code. But I'm afraid it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheDareback looks ok to me, maybe problem in reducer? btw what purpose of dispatch inside useEffect?

Comment: You're probably right because I can also see in Redux DevTool that the updated status is only after the refresh and not immediately (slice included in the first question)

Comment: @TheDareback so your postToDoItem post items on backend, but it doesn't store anything on local store. And after refresh getToDoItems get updates from backend and store it in local store. Also you should use either redux-thunk or RTKQ or redux-saga for async actions.

Comment: but if you want to see immediate result just put setItem(/* data */) into postToDoItem, it should work